# grails springsecurity's LoginController throws NotSerializableException

Tags: grails, spring-security, login-control

I have a nicely working grails 2.5.0 project (called lss) with spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 plugged in. I created a dev war file of the project, ran in on a server on Tomcat8.0 and accessed it using the URL http://localhost:8080/lss/login/auth. All works fine - I am able to login in with my credentials as provided in the BootStrap.

Then, I switched the localhost name for the server name and tried to access it using the URL http://devServer.prods.ca:8080/lss/login/auth. Again, the project is alive and I see the login page no problem, but now when I enter my credentials they are consumed, username and password fields are reset clean, and no redirection whatsoever, I simply stay on the login page!

Looking at the stacktrace.log file, I see the following exception:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
...
```

Any suggestions on how to remedy this please for a successfully authenticatable deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, with due credit to this [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/making-domain-classes-Serializable-td2297068.html). Indeed the problem was boldly injecting springSecurityService with the def keyword inside the User domain class - a plugin whose controllers are not serializable. By making these edits in the User domain class:

1. replace *transient springSecurityService* by *transient grailsApplication*
2. make sure the updated statement is *static transients = ['grailsApplication']*
3. create the method:

   def getSss() {
       grailsApplication.mainContext.springSecurityService
   }
4. update the only method that uses the springSecurityService to:

   protected void encodePassword() {
       password = sss?.passwordEncoder ? sss.encodePassword(password) : password
   }

All worked fine and was able to access and use the application with the server name smoothly.